# PHP login check flow

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Im having trouble with a php login script (below). I want to redirect to nouser.php if someone enters a username that does not exist and to wrongpass.php if the wrong password (but a valid username) is entered. The below code almost works. If I comment out the entire wrong password section then the nouser section works as expected displaying the nouser page , but if I leave the wrong password section in I get the wrongpass.php page for both nouser and wrong password situations. If I put a valid user in but with wrong password then I get wrong password (correct behavior).
Simply put , how can i make sure that I get redirect to nouser.php if there is nouser of this name and not the wrongpass.php page..

```
<?php
            $username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//connect to the database here

require_once 'includes/login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());


$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "SELECT password, salt
        FROM users
        WHERE username = '$username';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
//wrong user section
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such user exists
{
    header('Location: nouser.php');
}
//wrong password section
$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );
if($hash != $userData['password']) //incorrect password
{
    header('Location: wrongpass.php');
}
//login successful


?>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that mqsql_ is deprecated. You should instead use mysqli. I recently made the switch and actually the OO nature (you can but don't have to use) of mysqli is much nicer

Comment: it is also worth noting that you are giving information away by having 2 destination scripts for nouser and wrong password. catch my meaning ?

Comment: You should only advise that the username and password combination given is not valid, otherwise you are telling people that they have guessed a valid username now they just have to guess the password.

Comment: yeah , i understand about not giving away what the user is doing incorrectly (username or password) , this is just an initial setup for testing and I will change things. Also , it is for an internal app that i dont need too secure either but i take you point and it would be good practice to change it anyway. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add die() to stop the script

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
    header('location:nouser.php');
    die();
}
```

Has not yet test the code.

Comment: that seems to works thanks. I thought about that but thought it might break something else. Should have tried it really.

Comment: yeah break die exit bailout

Comment: @user2332903 but I don't think you should create your own login.php many authentication plugin will help you and more safer.

Comment: you can also use `exit()` :)

Comment: @gilbertxenodike - im doing this for two reasons. One an application for my own business that will be accessed internally only so safety isnt a huge issue and secondly , im doing it to learn so doing it myself will have much more value than using a plugin.  If it was something i was building for a customer / client etc id agree